# Scrapy, create queues for spiders using a extendable queue pool mechanism

Tags: scrapy, queue

Scrapy starts 8 crawlers all at the same time. 3 of them are on the same IP and so we set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` this is per spider, but then we also need the 3 spiders that access the same server (ip) to wait for each other.

How and where can we create some kind of queue mechanism in the `BaseSpider()` that if one of the 3 spiders was already started then the other 2 need to wait.

**Possible solution A:**

- Suppose the 3 spiders are called `Heuy, Dewey and Louie`
- create `wait_for list variable` that is set on spider level. For `Heuy` it is empty, for `Dewey` it is set to `[Heuy, Louie]` and for `Louie` it is set to `[Heuy, Dewey]`
- In this example all 3 would start and run into some if/else logic in BaseSpider **init** where we a) check for the `wait_for list variable` then access it and see if any of the other spiders are running, if so then we pause() the current spider. For `Heuy` this would mean I wat for nobody and start. `Dewey and Louie` have a `wait_for` and because `Heuy` is running the both will pause.
- In the close spider logic of BaseSpider we do the same check again, only this time we access the all waiting spiders list, get their `wait_for` list, check if any of the `wait_for` spiders is still running (is it? when close spider is still being accessed ...) and unpause() the spider (which is `Louie` or `Dewey`).
- Then when the 2nd spider finishes it does the same check again and starts the 3rd spider

**Possible solution B:**

- Suppose the 3 spiders are called `Heuy, Dewey and Louie`
- create `crawl_pool_queue` on BaseSpider level.
- create `crawl_pool` = `ducks` variable that is set on spider level for `Heuy, Dewey and Louie`.
- In this example all 3 would start and run into some if/else logic in BaseSpider **init** where we check for the existance of `crawl_pool`
- If it exists then we access all running spiders and see if already 1 in the same `crawl_pool` are running. If not then start ... if yes then push to `crawl_pool_queue`
- The paused spiders are stored in crawl_pool_queue using a dict containing a list per key for waiting spiders ---- this allows us to have more than 1 queue.
- If a spider finishes(closes) then we try to access `crawl_pool` if it does not exist then there is no spider waiting; if it does exist then we access `crawl_pool_queue` and find the next spider name that needs to run, pop it from the list and start it
- Etc Etc

To me solution B sound like the best solution. Although I am not sure.

**So my question is:**

- what is the best way to create a scalable crawler_queue where spiders wait for each other when we cannot access the same domain at the same time?
- what is the best place to store this logic? Would it be **init** for pausing the spiders?
- what is the best place to store this logic? Would it be closed() for unpausing the spiders? -- I mean is the spider then really closed already?
- can we create some code that can be used by the community for this to share

**Sample code for solution B**

```
class BaseShirtsSpider(Spider):

    # dict to store pools and lists of waiting crawlers
    crawl_pool_queue = {}
    # default there is no crawl pool, not ture if I have to define it as False
    crawl_pool = False

    # Maybe a method even before init_login (ideally before even making any request, or at the minimum the 1st loginpage)
    def init_login(self, meta=None):
        # Only check logic if crawl_pool is defined
        if self.crawl_pool:
            # How can I retrieve all spiders and their state running/paused
            for spider in crawler.spiders():
                # If we find a RUNNING spider and it has the same crawl pool then pause it() + add to crawl_pool_queue
                if spider.crawler.engine.state = 1 and spider.crawler.engine.crawl_pool = self.crawl_pool:
                    crawl_pool_queue[crawl_pool].append(spider.crawler.name)
                    spider.crawler.engine.pause()
                    break

    def closed(self, reason):
        # Only check logic if crawl_pool is defined
        if self.crawl_pool:
            # How can I retrieve all spiders and their state running/paused
            for spider in crawler.spiders():
                # If we find a WAITING spider and it has the same crawl pool then unpause it() + remote from crawl_pool_queue
                if spider.crawler.engine.state = 0 and spider.crawler.engine.crawl_pool = self.crawl_pool:
                    crawl_pool_queue[crawl_pool].remove(spider.crawler.name)
                    spider.crawler.engine.unpause()
                    break
        super().closed(reason)

class HueySpider(BaseShirtsSpider):
    name = 'huey'
    crawl_pool = 'ducks'
    start_urls = ['samedomain.com']

class DeweySpider(BaseShirtsSpider):
    name = 'dewey'
    crawl_pool = 'ducks'
    start_urls = ['samedomain.com']

class LouieSpider(BaseShirtsSpider):
    name = 'louie'
    crawl_pool = 'ducks'
    start_urls = ['samedomain.com']

class DonaldSpider(BaseShirtsSpider):
    name = 'donald'
    start_urls = ['someotherdomain.com']
```